# Is there any advantage to storing static data in an image rather than an array?

Tags: javascript, memory

I'm working on a Javascript game that involves a world map, and am drawing/storing that map as an image.  The colour of each pixel on the image represents what that cell on the map will contain.

Would there be any memory consumption advantage to loading the image and reading the colours from it on the fly, rather than preloading and storing it as an array?

Also, would there likely be a severe speed drop from doing that?

I'll probably end up loading only segments of it as needed, but that same question would still stand.  The current test image is 1000x1000 pixels.

Comment: I've not tried it but I'd assume reading a pixel value off an image is more expensive because it's not exactly `myArray[x][y]` to retrieve the value but you have to involve some parsing of the data. With that said, whether it's significantly slower or not, I don't know.

Comment: if you need the image anyway, then yeah, it saves memory to recycle it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. There isn't, unless you care about drawing an image vs writing thousands of numbers by hand.

Fastest way to retrieve data from an image is to take "Image like object" (basically either canvas or actual Image) and call `.getImageData(x, y, width, height)` to get an array of pixel values.

If anything, that would add """overhead""" (negligible) since you'd now have 4 times more values. Each pixel is stored over 4 JavaScript *numbers*, since you could just have each tile as a single integer identifier instead, that would waste memory.

Although, imageData object allows you to take the rect from it and if you will have 4 tile layers, then the way pixels are stored is the best.

If you want to store your level as an image then go for it, I'd still probably store the level in a flat array, because if I needed 5th layer, I could just switch few numbers and voila, now my system has 5 layers, you can't do that with image data.

Either way, just try to ensure that no matter which way you do it, you have low level of nesting (flat array for all layers is better than 4 arrays for each layer) and retrieving value from an array is fast enough for what you do.